# Javascript count down time is out of sync with server

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, timer, synchronization

I am trying to sync the time between the client and server so that a countdown operates at the same time. At the moment the clients timer executes faster than the servers timer (by a considerable amount) and I don't understand how.

For my server application it's wrote in C# and uses web sockets to communicate with the user. The server sends a message which contains data about the timer and how long is left. The following function is the called with the data;

```
function setTimer(secondsLeft) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + secondsLeft);

  setInterval(function() {
    var time = Math.abs((new Date() - d) / 1000);
    var minutes = ("00" + Math.floor(time / 60)).slice(-2);
    var seconds = ("00" + Math.floor(time % 60)).slice(-2);

    $(".timer-cycle").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    $(".timer-cycle").show();
  }, 1000);
}
```

I am aware that the setInterval can cause a delay of up to 500ms but the difference between the time is a lot more than this. Originally after starting the timer they are in sync with one another. However, after time progress' you begin to notice that they're off. To where a 10 minute timer is like 1-2 minutes off.

For the method of obtaining the end time and sending the time remaining I use a DateTime object using the UTC offset. Like so;

```
this.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Seconds);
this.Client.SendTimer(Seconds);
```

For the purpose of checking if it's expired I have a timer that runs every 1 seconds and prints the time on the console. Here is the code behind the command;

```
TimeSpan TimeLeft = this.Expire.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow);
Console.Log($"[DEBUG] M: {TimeLeft.Minutes} S: {TimeLeft.Seconds}");
```

**Does anyone know of any way in order to make them sync up exactly (or at least close enough). My other idea was to send the seconds left every time the ticker ticks in C# rather than processing it on the client but don't want to send that many messages.**

P.s. I have also tried using a setinterval in javascript which deducts the secondsLeft by one each time it executes rather than converting to date object.

---

This is another method which I attempted;

```
function setTimer(secondsLeft) {

  setInterval(function() {
    secondsLeft -= 1;

    var minutes = ("00" + Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60)).slice(-2);
    var seconds = ("00" + Math.floor(secondsLeft % 60)).slice(-2);

    $(".timer-cycle").html(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    $(".timer-cycle").show();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: if you want to be exactly same with other, you should keep sending your time information from server to client. But if you dont want to keep sending time information, just send hour, minute, seconds from server and in the client put them in `setInterval()` and repeat it every 1000ms than do timing things. (e.g. increase minute when second become 60 and reset it back to 0)

Comment: No an event happens in C# after the time has expired. For example if the user is doing a mission they have a maximum of 15 minutes to complete it. So they can see the time in the bottom left.

Comment: The javascript one is running faster all the time (it's in sync with my PC clock though). Tested on several different clients on several different machines, they all have the same result.

Comment: done more testing.. when using a client on actual server the timers are in sync. But if i use on my pc they're out of sync.

Comment: I can't give you any meaningful suggestions without seeing the entire class containing the `TimeLeft` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.Log($"[DEBUG] M: {Time.Minutes} S: {Time.Seconds}");
```

should be replaced with:

```
Console.Log($"[DEBUG] M: {Math.Floor(TimeLeft.TotalMinutes)} S: {TimeLeft.Seconds}");
```

The issue is that you are using the `Time` variable when you should be using `TimeLeft`. Also the Minutes property can only be from 0-59, while `TotalMinutes` will work for any value (e.g. over an hour).

Comment: My bad I did actually change this when i was checking it but still same issue. It's as if the timer is running slower not sure why

Comment: Please update your post with your actual current code.

Comment: You should fix `TimeLeft.Minutes` as per my above example.

Comment: It's also out by the seconds as well though, it's not just minutes. And it's not just one second so rounding seconds down won't work. Thanks though